# Why DynamoDB scan with Limit and FilterExpression not return the items that match the filter requirements?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need make a scan with limit and a condition on DynamoDB.

The [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#ScanQueryLimit) says:

> In a response, DynamoDB returns all the matching results within the scope of the Limit value. For example, if you issue a Query or a Scan request with a Limit value of 6 and without a filter expression, DynamoDB returns the first six items in the table that match the specified key conditions in the request (or just the first six items in the case of a Scan with no filter). If you also supply a FilterExpression value, DynamoDB will return the items in the first six that also match the filter requirements (the number of results returned will be less than or equal to 6).

**The code (NODEJS):**

```
var params = {
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {"#user": "User"},
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {":user": parseInt(user.id)},
    FilterExpression: "#user = :user and attribute_not_exists(Removed)",
    Limit: 2,
    TableName: "XXXX"
};

DynamoDB.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        dataToSend.message = "Unable to query. Error: " + err.message;
    } else if (data.Items.length == 0) {
        dataToSend.message = "No results were found.";
    } else {
        dataToSend.data = data.Items;
        console.log(dataToSend);
    }
});
```

**Table XXXX definitions:**

- Primary partition key: User (Number)
- Primary sort key: Identifier (String)
- INDEX:

  - Index Name: RemovedIndex
  - Type: GSI
  - Partition key: Removed (Number)
  - Sort key: -
  - Attributes: ALL

In code above, if I remove the `Limit` parameter, DynamoDB will return the items that match the filter requirements. So, the conditions are ok. But when I scan with `Limit` parameter, the result is empty.

The XXXX table, has 5 items. Only the 2 firsts have the `Removed` attribute. When I scan without `Limit` parameter, DynamoDB returns the 3 items without `Removed` attribute.

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the docs that you quoted:

> If you also supply a FilterExpression value, DynamoDB will return the
>   items **in the first six** that also match the filter requirements

By combining Limit and FilterExpression you have told DynamoDB to only look at the first two items in the table, and evaluate the FilterExpression against those items. Limit in DynamoDB can be confusing because it works differently from `limit` in a SQL expression in a RDBMS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did not understand the doc, you clarified to me. Do you have any tips on how I can use `limit` just like a SQL expression in the RDBMS?

Comment: There's definitely some confusion over this: https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels/issues/12 How is this useful behaviour? Surely scanning until you either have 6 items that match the filter or you reach the end of the table would be more useful?

Comment: @Clarkie It is useful because it allows you to limit the number of records a Scan operation evaluates, for performance reasons. Just because it doesn't work the same as an RDBMS doesn't mean it isn't useful. Also your comment on Github about there being "some confusion over what the docs say" seems incorrect to me. The docs (as I quoted in my answer) are perfectly clear. The confusion comes from people who assume `limit` works the same way in DynamoDB as it does in an RDBMS without taking the time to read the docs.

Comment: @Mark B But how to achieve this "limit" as in a SQL expression in a RDBMS?

Comment: @SimonPertersen Did you find out the answer? Dynamo's documentation is horrible. Simple things seem to be hidden somewhere in hole.

Comment: @bozzmob I havn't found a solution yet, still in doubt. This is due to the basic design idears in Dynamodb, where filters are added after limit.

Comment: @SimonPertersen looking at few things, I feel DynamoDB is not the right choice for my usecase. MongoDB has much better querying patterns. I might go with MongoDB or Cassandra.

Comment: @bozzmob well depends, on what your doing, my approach is to use dynamodb for simple CRUD, then i use AWS lambda into index certain tables to elastic search and then do heavy queries in elastic

Comment: @SimonPertersen, but if I cannot use something like elastic, only the dynamo? I was thinking to query all the data, then return the data sliced with the length, but this is a bad solution because I also need pagination...

Comment: @thismarcoantonio you can paginate, its just to parse 'startKey'

Comment: @SimonPertersen but how can I filter in all table fields, limit to 2 and paginate? If I limit to 2, it filters only the two first table fields.

Comment: @thismarcoantonio That is due to the shitty idea that they have in dynamo, which applies filters after they are returned - the best way to resolve this is with indexes - or use streams to have them in elastic search and do complicated queries

Comment: @SimonPertersen I see... when you talk about indexes, are talking about secondary indexes? If yes, global indexes or local indexes? Because I need to pay for every global index, sure?

Comment: @thismarcoantonio local indexes are for if you need a secondary range key for the original hashkey, global are if you need new global hashkeys

Comment: @SimonPertersen Thank you!

Comment: You can solve this by checking the LastEvaluatedKey from your result and re-fetching from the as long as the result does not match your limit and there is a LastEvaluatedKey. Sound more like a workaround, but that was the only thing i could figure out.

Answer (score 5):

Also ran into this issue, i guess you will just have to scan the whole table to a max of 1 MB

Scan
The result set from a Scan is limited to 1 MB per call. You can use the `LastEvaluatedKey` from the scan response to retrieve more results.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get what you need by using a secondary index. Using the classic RDB example, customer - order example: you have one table for customers and one for orders. The Orders table has a Key consisting of Customer - HASH, Order - RANGE. So if you wanted to get the latest 10 orders, there would be no way to do it without a scan

But if you create a Global Secondary Index on orders of "Some Constant" -- HASH, Date RANGE, and queried against that index, they query would do what you want and only charge you for the RCUs involved with the records returned.  No expensive scan needed.  Note, writes will be more expensive, but in most cases, there are many more reads than writes.

Now you have your original problem if you want to get the 10 biggest orders for a day larger than $1000. The query would return the last 10 orders, and then filter out those less than $1000.

In this case, you could create a computed key of Date-OrderAmount, and queries against that index would return what you want.

It's not as simple as SQL, but you need to think about access patterns in SQL too.  If if you have a lot of data, you need to create Indexes in SQL or the DB will happily to table scans on your behalf, which will impair performance and raise your costs.

Note that everything I proposed is normalized in the sense that there is only one source of truth.   You are not duplicating data -- you are merely recasting views of it to get what you need from DynamoDB.

Bear in mind that the CONSTANT as a HASH s subject to the 10GB per partition limit, so you would need to design around it if you had a lot of active data. For example, depending on your expected access pattern, you could use Customer and not a constant as a HASH.  Or use STreams to organize the data (or subsets) in other ways.

Answer (score -1):

Small hack - Iterate till you get the results

```
lastEvaluatedKey = null;
do {

    if(lastEvaluatedKey != null) {
        // query or scan data with last evaluated key 
    } else {
        // query or scan data WITHOUT last evaluated key 
    }        

    lastEvaluatedKey == key of last item retrieved

} while(lastEvaluatedKey != null && retrievedResultSize == 0); // == 0 or < yourLimit
```

If the number of items retrieved is 0 and lastEvaluatedKey is not null that means it has scanned or queried the number of rows which match to your limit. (and result size is zero because they didn't match the filter expression)