# Load data from DynamoDB by paging (Amazon Web Service)

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm developing mobile applications using the Amazon Web Service backend. I'm having trouble with DynamoDB, my problem is to take the data by Paging and sort the data according by date. I used the Limit, but when I use the Filter Expression then return results not as expected.  Hope you help me! Thank all

```
let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()
    queryExpression.scanIndexForward = true
    queryExpression.limit = 10
    queryExpression.exclusiveStartKey = exclusiveStartKey
    queryExpression.indexName = "id-createDate-index"
    queryExpression.keyConditionExpression = "id = :val"
    queryExpression.filterExpression = "name = :val2"
    queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = [":val" : "A",":val2":"B"]
    dynamoDBObjectMapper .query(TestDB.self, expression: queryExpression) .continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
        if (task.error != nil) {
            print("Error: \(task.error)")
        } else {
            if (task.result != nil) {
                let pagniatedOutput = task.result as? AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput
                for r in pagniatedOutput?.items as! [TestDB] {
                    print("\(r.createDate) + \(r.id)")
                }
                print(pagniatedOutput?.lastEvaluatedKey)
            }
        }
        return nil
    })
```

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()
    queryExpression.scanIndexForward = true
    queryExpression.limit = 10
    queryExpression.exclusiveStartKey = exclusiveStartKey
    queryExpression.indexName = "id-createDate-index"
    queryExpression.keyConditionExpression = "id = :val"
    queryExpression.filterExpression = "name = :val2"
   queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = [":val" : "A",":val2":"B"]

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778506/why-dynamodb-scan-with-limit-and-filterexpression-not-return-the-items-that-matc/38778596?noredirect=1#comment64928790_38778596 You need to remove the `Limit` from your query, because it doesn't work the way you think it does. You will just need to perform a query and then display the first 10 items that come back.

Comment: Thanks, but I just want to take the 10 row once, and use lastEvaluatedKey to take the next page. Can do that with the  Dynamodb? @MarkB

Comment: @CuongDu No you can't do that with DynamoDB.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB, data retrieve max 1MB, it is too large, so is there any method I can get the data in small pieces?