# Unable to limit Dynamo Query in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am having problems to limit the query results in a DynamoDB Document Client Query. This is my parameters object:

```
var params = {
  TableName : config.aws.dynamo.table,
  IndexName: "CreationDate-index",
  KeyConditionExpression: "Area = :area and CreationDate > :creationDate",
  FilterExpression: "IsSuccessFull = :isSuccessFul",
  ScanIndexForward: true,
  Limit: 10,
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":area":someArea,
    ":creationDate":someDate,
  }
};
```

When I  remove the Limit I get several results more than 20, but if I add the limit I only get one result, I have been reading that the filter expression could cause this behavior but I don't understand why.

Comment: Please see my answer to the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778506/why-dynamodb-scan-with-limit-and-filterexpression-not-return-the-items-that-matc/38778596#38778596 It is also the answer for your question.

Comment: Thank You, i understand better the behavior of the Limit with the FilterExpression